# Multiple loops with one jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I was wandering if its possible to have 2 or more loops/each with one ajax call? What I am trying to achieve is a golf scorecard in which I get the data for the scorecard and the players in one json/ajax call...

Here is how i get the scorecard.

scorecard.php:

```
$scorecard = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ga_turndata WHERE fk_turnid = 1 ORDER BY hole_no ASC LIMIT 18");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $scorecard[] = array('hole' => $row['hole_no'], 'par' => $row['par'], 'hcp' => $row['hcp']);
}
```

jquery to get the data:

```
$.getJSON('http://mypage.com/json/scorecard.php', function(data) {

        var array = [];

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {

            array.push($("#theholes").append("<li>"+val.hole+"</li>"));

        });
});
```

This part works like a charm :-). But when trying to add this to the scorecard.php:

```
$scorecard[] = array('user' => 'Jane Doe', 'id' => '89', 'useraStrokes' => '5');
$scorecard[] = array('user' => 'Jemaine Dice', 'id' => '245', 'useraStrokes' => '17');
$scorecard[] = array('user' => 'Jimmie Gallon', 'id' => '16', 'useraStrokes' => '13');
```

I then, off course, get 3 li's more... Is there anyway I can separate these or should I make a ajax call twice? One for the scorecard, and one for the players?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You can walk trough your `scorecard`-array and check the key (hole or user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a single JSON object containing two arrays: `scorecard` and `players`. Then, in your AJAX success callback, you'd simply iterate over them separately:

```
$.getJSON('http://mypage.com/json/scorecard.php', function(data) {
    var array = [];
    $.each(data.scorecard, function (i, val) {
        array.push($("#theholes").append("<li>"+val.hole+"</li>"));
    });

    $.each(data.players, function(i, player) {
        // do something with this player
    });
});
```

The PHP side would look something like this:

```
$scorecard = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ga_turndata WHERE fk_turnid = 1 ORDER BY hole_no ASC LIMIT 18");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $scorecard[] = array('hole' => $row['hole_no'], 'par' => $row['par'], 'hcp' => $row['hcp']);
}

$players = array();

$players[] = array('user' => 'Jane Doe', 'id' => '89', 'useraStrokes' => '5');
$players[] = array('user' => 'Jemaine Dice', 'id' => '245', 'useraStrokes' => '17');
$players[] = array('user' => 'Jimmie Gallon', 'id' => '16', 'useraStrokes' => '13');

$data = array('scorecard' => $scorecard, 'players' => $players);

// possibly some other stuff?

return json_encode($data);
```

Disclaimer: I've never learnt PHP, this is just based on rough knowledge picked up from reading on SO; apologies for any mistakes above.

Comment: How do the PHP part looks like?

Comment: @Mansa I've never really learnt PHP, other than what I've picked up through reading questions and answers on SO. I could take a stab at it (though there'd likely be some minor errors), but you've already demonstrated all of the required knowledge in your question; you'd just be applying the same concepts.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way but not the best to loop twice

```
 $.getJSON('http://mypage.com/json/scorecard.php', function(data) {

        var array = [];

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {

            array.push($("#theholes").append("<li>"+val.hole+"</li>"));

        });
    $.each(data, function (j, val) {

            array.push($("#scorecard").append("<li>"+val.user+"</li>"));

        });
});
```

The better way to check if val.user or val.hole exist if yes build li and save it in variable and only after loop do append

Answer (score 0):

One way is to return your ajax call with values in corresponding array, such as $data['scorecards'=>$scorecards, 'users'=>$users ] etc.

In jquery, simply get scorecards and users from data.scorecards and data.users respectively.

This avoids calling the ajax twice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Where do i use the $data?